# I was requested to run exploratory factor analysis (EFA) on 3 variables. Is there a minimum number of variables to use in EFA?

Tags: factor-analysis

I was requested to run exploratory factor analysis (EFA) on 3 variables to see if they would load into a single factor. And if they do, then use the factor scores in the further analysis instead of those variables. Is there a minimum number of variables to use in EFA?

Thank you very much!

Comment: There is no limit that I know of, although I don't see the point of doing EFA on just three variables. Its designed to reduce large number of variables to a smaller set of factors.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I think myself